# How to have a file to contain all includes?

Tags: c++, header, include

I have an age-old question.
I'm developing an infrastructure code in C++ which has a lot of headers to be included in each header file.
I ideally would like to have everything included in a header file and then just to include that header file. That of course creates infinite-loop problem where a header is included in a header that includes the same header.

Doing #ifndef or #pragma once is also not going to help.
Is there any other clever way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: _"That of course creates infinite-loop problem where a header is included in a header that includes the same header."_ It shouldn't? "_Doing #ifndef or #pragma once is also not going to help."_ Why not?

Comment: This is quite a common thing to do: anyone with precompiled headers is doing it!

Comment: I have done this for decades using precompiled headers. Although with that said there are still things you don't put in the precompiled header. It's there to put in headers that don't change or don't often change since recompiling the precompiled header can take several minutes depending on your project.

Comment: Assume "superheader.h" has "A.h" and "B.h". Within "A.h" I include "superheader.h" and do the same within "B.h". If I have "superheader.h" guarded with #paragma once, it looks like that it's included either in "A.h" or "B.h" (assume "A.h" gets compiled first). "B.h" internal constructs keep nagging that that it doesn't know what "A.h" internal function/variable/etc are.

Answer (score 1):

> That of course creates infinite-loop problem where a header is included in a header that includes the same header.

Simply exclude the "superheader" from the set of headers that the "superheader" includes. That way you don't get the problem.

That said, doing this is likely going to cause translation units including the "superheader" to include headers unnecessarily which may adversely affect compilation times. As such, I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: Do you know a good approach besides just including whatever that is necessary in each file?